# How to solve this error "failed to initialize PI MR pool sized 128 for QID 1" when connect nvmeof

Tags: rdma, nvme

I want to use nvme-of(rdma). My Linux kernel version is 5.4.0-28-generic with Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. I download MLNX_OFED_LINUX-5.4-3.6.8.1-ubuntu20.04-x86_64.tgz and install it successfully. I can load all the modules such as nvmet,nvmet-rdma,nvme-rdma. But when I use the connect command like" sudo nvme connect -t rdma -q nvme-subsystem-name -n nvme-subsystem-name  -a 10.x.x.4 -s 4420", I got this error:

```
[ 500.247452] nvme nvme2: creating 16 I/O queues.
[ 500.288017] nvme nvme2: failed to initialize PI MR pool sized 128 for QID 1
[ 500.315821] nvme nvme2: rdma connection establishment failed (-22)
```

I really don't know how to solve it, please help me.

I have tried to reduce or rise the version of kernel, but it didn't take effect. I want to connect the other machine successfully.